# Generated txt file not pushing to GitHub repo

Tags: java, maven, github, github-actions, cicd

My question is: I have Maven Project that generates txt file and I'm running it from GitHub Actions. Generated files not pushing into GitHub repo.

Do I need to add some script into yaml?

```yaml
name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean test -DsuiteXMLFILE=testng.xml
```

[image: screenshot from github]

[image: ss from framework]

These two files not updating at all.

All paths are correct (used relative path).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create and save files using PowerShell in GitHub action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75320606/how-to-create-and-save-files-using-powershell-in-github-action)

Comment: Why is code changing source code even if it's in test area. Such things should be done in `target` directory and never in `src` because it's under version control... The question is why do you need such a change?